# Python Tkinter Long Distance Calls

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am tasked with creating a program using radiobuttons that will show the charges for calling at certain times of the days long distances. For the daytime, it's .07 per minute, evening is .12 per minute, and off peak is .05 per minute. For some reason, i can't seem to figure out how to get the amount of minutes talked multiplied by the specific time of day charges and the output the answer.

This is my code so far and I'm getting an output of $0:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox

def main():
    my_gui = TelephoneRatesGUI()

class TelephoneRatesGUI():

    def __init__(self):
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()

        #create 3 frames
        self.top_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.mid_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.bottom_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)

        #create an intvar object
        self.radio_var = tkinter.IntVar()

        #set the intVar object to 1.
        self.radio_var.set(1)

        #create the radiobutton widgets in the top_frame
        self.rb1 = tkinter.Radiobutton(self.top_frame,
                                       text='Daytime(6:00am - 5:59pm)',
                                       variable=self.radio_var,
                                       value=.07)
        self.rb2 = tkinter.Radiobutton(self.top_frame,
                                       text='Evening(6:00pm - 11:59pm)',
                                       variable=self.radio_var,
                                       value=.12)
        self.rb3 = tkinter.Radiobutton(self.top_frame,
                                       text='Off-Peak(12:00am - 5:59am)',
                                       variable=self.radio_var,
                                       value=.05)

        #pack the radiobuttons
        self.rb1.pack()
        self.rb2.pack()
        self.rb3.pack()

        #create widgets for the middle frame
        self.prompt_label = tkinter.Label(self.mid_frame,
                                          text='Enter the number of minutes:')
        self.num_min = tkinter.Entry(self.mid_frame,
                                     width=10)

        #pack the mid frame's widgets
        self.prompt_label.pack(side='left')
        self.num_min.pack(side='left')

        #create a display charges button and a quit button
        self.dis_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame,
                                         text='Display Charges',
                                         command=self.show_charges)
        self.quit_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame,
                                          text='Quit',
                                          command=self.main_window.destroy)

        #pack the buttons
        self.dis_button.pack(side='left')
        self.quit_button.pack(side='left')

        #pack the frames
        self.top_frame.pack()
        self.mid_frame.pack()
        self.bottom_frame.pack()

        #start the mainloop
        tkinter.mainloop()

    def show_charges(self):
        charges = float(self.radio_var.get())

        minutes = float(self.num_min.get())

        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Total Charges', 'Your total charges = $' +
                                    format(float(charges*minutes)))

main()
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Just asking "why doesn't this code work" is off topic here. What specific problem are you having? Getting the values from the UI? Doing the calculation? Putting the results back in the UI? Something else? Have you verified that in `show_charges`, `charges` and `minutes` are what you expect them to be?

Comment: My output isn't correct. it's just $0 when it should be multiplying the amount of minutes you enter into the program by the set values for charges

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `self.radio_var` to be a `tkinter.DoubleVar`. I made the following change and got the program to work:

```
self.radio_var = tkinter.DoubleVar()
```

**Note:** The fact that you were unable to solve this on your own indicates that you were not looking at the console output of your program. Next time, run your program from the console, so you can see the exception traceback.

**Update:** In a comment you say that you were running your program in a console but you did not see an error. When I ran your program, I got this traceback:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "old.py", line 73, in show_charges
    charges = float(self.radio_var.get())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 355, in get
    return self._tk.getint(self._tk.globalgetvar(self._name))
TypeError: getint() argument must be str, not float
```

If you are not seeing this type of output with your original code, I have trouble believing that you know what I mean when I say "run your program from the console".

Comment: I have been  but it wasn't giving me an error, it was just outputting $0 as the answer. Plus, i haven't even learned about doublevar() yet

Comment: either way, thank you for your help. I formatted the answer and everything is now working perfectly.

Comment: shoot, i may have figured that out but didn't update my code. That was my bad, i'm sorry.